# Can you get a keypress event for the phone call key in Flash Lite?

Tags: events, mobile-phones, keypress, flashlite, phone-call

All mobiles have a green dialing key. Do you get an event for this in Flash Lite 3.0 or above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried listening for a keypress?

Test it with this code in your Scene 1's actions pane:

```
onKeyDown() {
  trace("Key received: " + Key.getCode())
}

Key.addListener(this)
```